# I am create a model in spark by using its pyspark.ml.regression.LinearRegression

Tags: pyspark

I am building a model but getting error

```
from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression
lr=LinearRegression(featuresCol = 'features', labelCol='label',maxIter=10)
lrModel=lr.fit(trainingdata)
```

> IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Column features must be of type struct,values:array> but was actually struct,values:array>.

Answer (score 0):

This will go like this.
Let's assume you have a dataframe with name df and columns in it are "X1", "X2", "Y".

First you will have to group independent variables - "X1", "X2" into a single column named "features". Below is a code to do that.

```
new_df = VectorAssembler(inputCols=["X1", "X2"], outputCol="features")
```

Now, your new_df will have columns - "X1", "X2", "features", "Y".

Now, is the time to run Linear Regression like

```
model = LinearRegression(labelCol="Y").fit(training_data)
```

Comment: I have create a dataframe with two columns using Vector.dense. def transformToLabelPoint(instr):
    lp=(float(instr[0]),Vectors.dense([instr[1],instr[2],instr[4]]))
    return lp
autoLp=autoVectors.map(transformToLabelPoint)                                                                   autoDF=sqlContext.createDataFrame(autoLp,["label","features"])                                         (trainingdata,testdata)=autoDF.randomSplit([0.9,0.1])                                                           
lr=LinearRegression(featuresCol = 'features', labelCol='label',maxIter=10)